# D3 - Icicle Partitioning minmum cell size?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3js, and I really like the library.

I intended to use Sunbrust and Icicle visualizations to show dependency trees of applications, in which the user can see the dependency hierarchy (who depends on who, etc...).
However, the icicle and sunburst visualizations always produce some "cells" that are too small, requiring the user to hover the cell to get the label.

Is it possible to tell d3 to create these cells with a minium height?
So that each cell can display the label inside and not require users to hover these cells?

See here:
[image]

See Observable code here:https://observablehq.com/@d3/icicle

See fiddle, here:
https://jsfiddle.net/68q0thc5/

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    chart = Icicle(getData(), {
        value: d => d.size, // size of each node (file); null for internal nodes (folders)
        label: d => d.name, // display name for each cell
        title: (d, n) => `${n.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join(".")}\n${n.value.toLocaleString("en")}`, // hover text
        link: (d, n) => n.children
            ? `https://github.com/prefuse/Flare/tree/master/flare/src/${n.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/")}`
            : `https://github.com/prefuse/Flare/blob/master/flare/src/${n.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/")}.as`,
        width: 1152,
        height: 2400
    })

    document.getElementById("chart").appendChild(chart)

    // Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
    // Released under the ISC license.
    // https://observablehq.com/@d3/icicle
    function Icicle(data, { // data is either tabular (array of objects) or hierarchy (nested objects)
        path, // as an alternative to id and parentId, returns an array identifier, imputing internal nodes
        id = Array.isArray(data) ? d => d.id : null, // if tabular data, given a d in data, returns a unique identifier (string)
        parentId = Array.isArray(data) ? d => d.parentId : null, // if tabular data, given a node d, returns its parent’s identifier
        children, // if hierarchical data, given a d in data, returns its children
        format = ",", // format specifier string or function for values
        value, // given a node d, returns a quantitative value (for area encoding; null for count)
        sort = (a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value), // how to sort nodes prior to layout
        label, // given a node d, returns the name to display on the rectangle
        title, // given a node d, returns its hover text
        link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
        linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links (if any)
        width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
        height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
        margin = 0, // shorthand for margins
        marginTop = margin, // top margin, in pixels
        marginRight = margin, // right margin, in pixels
        marginBottom = margin, // bottom margin, in pixels
        marginLeft = margin, // left margin, in pixels
        padding = 1, // cell padding, in pixels
        round = false, // whether to round to exact pixels
        color = d3.interpolateRainbow, // color scheme, if any
        fill = "#ccc", // fill for node rects (if no color encoding)
        fillOpacity = 0.6, // fill opacity for node rects
    } = {}) {

        // If id and parentId options are specified, or the path option, use d3.stratify
        // to convert tabular data to a hierarchy; otherwise we assume that the data is
        // specified as an object {children} with nested objects (a.k.a. the “flare.json”
        // format), and use d3.hierarchy.
        const root = path != null ? d3.stratify().path(path)(data)
            : id != null || parentId != null ? d3.stratify().id(id).parentId(parentId)(data)
                : d3.hierarchy(data, children);

        // Compute the values of internal nodes by aggregating from the leaves.
        value == null ? root.count() : root.sum(d => Math.max(0, value(d)));

        // Compute formats.
        if (typeof format !== "function") format = d3.format(format);

        // Sort the leaves (typically by descending value for a pleasing layout).
        if (sort != null) root.sort(sort);

        // Compute the partition layout. Note that x and y are swapped!
        d3.partition()
            .size([height - marginTop - marginBottom, width - marginLeft - marginRight])
            .padding(padding)
            .round(round)
            (root);

        // Construct a color scale.
        if (color != null) {
            color = d3.scaleSequential([0, root.children.length - 1], color).unknown(fill);
            root.children.forEach((child, i) => child.index = i);
        }

        const svg = d3.create("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", 10);

        const cell = svg
            .selectAll("a")
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", link == null ? null : d => link(d.data, d))
            .attr("target", link == null ? null : linkTarget)
            .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y0},${d.x0})`);

        cell.append("rect")
            .attr("width", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
            .attr("height", d => d.x1 - d.x0)
            .attr("fill", color ? d => color(d.ancestors().reverse()[1]?.index) : fill)
            .attr("fill-opacity", fillOpacity);

        const text = cell.filter(d => d.x1 - d.x0 > 10).append("text")
            .attr("x", 4)
            .attr("y", d => Math.min(9, (d.x1 - d.x0) / 2))
            .attr("dy", "0.32em");

        if (label != null) text.append("tspan")
            .text(d => label(d.data, d));

        text.append("tspan")
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
            .attr("dx", label == null ? null : 3)
            .text(d => format(d.value));

        if (title != null) cell.append("title")
            .text(d => title(d.data, d));

        return svg.node();
    }

    function getData() {
        return { "name": "flare", "children": [{ "name": "analytics", "children": [{ "name": "cluster", "children": [{ "name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938 }, { "name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812 }, { "name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714 }, { "name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743 }] }, { "name": "graph", "children": [{ "name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534 }, { "name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731 }, { "name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840 }, { "name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914 }, { "name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416 }] }, { "name": "optimization", "children": [{ "name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074 }] }] }, { "name": "animate", "children": [{ "name": "Easing", "size": 17010 }, { "name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842 }, { "name": "interpolate", "children": [{ "name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983 }, { "name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047 }, { "name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375 }, { "name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746 }, { "name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202 }, { "name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382 }, { "name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629 }, { "name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675 }, { "name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042 }] }, { "name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041 }, { "name": "Parallel", "size": 5176 }, { "name": "Pause", "size": 449 }, { "name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593 }, { "name": "Sequence", "size": 5534 }, { "name": "Transition", "size": 9201 }, { "name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975 }, { "name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116 }, { "name": "Tween", "size": 6006 }] }, { "name": "data", "children": [{ "name": "converters", "children": [{ "name": "Converters", "size": 721 }, { "name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294 }, { "name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800 }, { "name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314 }, { "name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220 }] }, { "name": "DataField", "size": 1759 }, { "name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165 }, { "name": "DataSet", "size": 586 }, { "name": "DataSource", "size": 3331 }, { "name": "DataTable", "size": 772 }, { "name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322 }] }, { "name": "display", "children": [{ "name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833 }, { "name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732 }, { "name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623 }, { "name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066 }] }, { "name": "flex", "children": [{ "name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116 }] }, { "name": "physics", "children": [{ "name": "DragForce", "size": 1082 }, { "name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336 }, { "name": "IForce", "size": 319 }, { "name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498 }, { "name": "Particle", "size": 2822 }, { "name": "Simulation", "size": 9983 }, { "name": "Spring", "size": 2213 }, { "name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681 }] }, { "name": "query", "children": [{ "name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616 }, { "name": "And", "size": 1027 }, { "name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891 }, { "name": "Average", "size": 891 }, { "name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893 }, { "name": "Comparison", "size": 5103 }, { "name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677 }, { "name": "Count", "size": 781 }, { "name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141 }, { "name": "Distinct", "size": 933 }, { "name": "Expression", "size": 5130 }, { "name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617 }, { "name": "Fn", "size": 3240 }, { "name": "If", "size": 2732 }, { "name": "IsA", "size": 2039 }, { "name": "Literal", "size": 1214 }, { "name": "Match", "size": 3748 }, { "name": "Maximum", "size": 843 }, { "name": "methods", "children": [{ "name": "add", "size": 593 }, { "name": "and", "size": 330 }, { "name": "average", "size": 287 }, { "name": "count", "size": 277 }, { "name": "distinct", "size": 292 }, { "name": "div", "size": 595 }, { "name": "eq", "size": 594 }, { "name": "fn", "size": 460 }, { "name": "gt", "size": 603 }, { "name": "gte", "size": 625 }, { "name": "iff", "size": 748 }, { "name": "isa", "size": 461 }, { "name": "lt", "size": 597 }, { "name": "lte", "size": 619 }, { "name": "max", "size": 283 }, { "name": "min", "size": 283 }, { "name": "mod", "size": 591 }, { "name": "mul", "size": 603 }, { "name": "neq", "size": 599 }, { "name": "not", "size": 386 }, { "name": "or", "size": 323 }, { "name": "orderby", "size": 307 }, { "name": "range", "size": 772 }, { "name": "select", "size": 296 }, { "name": "stddev", "size": 363 }, { "name": "sub", "size": 600 }, { "name": "sum", "size": 280 }, { "name": "update", "size": 307 }, { "name": "variance", "size": 335 }, { "name": "where", "size": 299 }, { "name": "xor", "size": 354 }, { "name": "_", "size": 264 }] }, { "name": "Minimum", "size": 843 }, { "name": "Not", "size": 1554 }, { "name": "Or", "size": 970 }, { "name": "Query", "size": 13896 }, { "name": "Range", "size": 1594 }, { "name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130 }, { "name": "Sum", "size": 791 }, { "name": "Variable", "size": 1124 }, { "name": "Variance", "size": 1876 }, { "name": "Xor", "size": 1101 }] }, { "name": "scale", "children": [{ "name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105 }, { "name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316 }, { "name": "LogScale", "size": 3151 }, { "name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770 }, { "name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435 }, { "name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839 }, { "name": "RootScale", "size": 1756 }, { "name": "Scale", "size": 4268 }, { "name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821 }, { "name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833 }] }, { "name": "util", "children": [{ "name": "Arrays", "size": 8258 }, { "name": "Colors", "size": 10001 }, { "name": "Dates", "size": 8217 }, { "name": "Displays", "size": 12555 }, { "name": "Filter", "size": 2324 }, { "name": "Geometry", "size": 10993 }, { "name": "heap", "children": [{ "name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354 }, { "name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233 }] }, { "name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335 }, { "name": "IPredicate", "size": 383 }, { "name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874 }, { "name": "math", "children": [{ "name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165 }, { "name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815 }, { "name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366 }] }, { "name": "Maths", "size": 17705 }, { "name": "Orientation", "size": 1486 }, { "name": "palette", "children": [{ "name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367 }, { "name": "Palette", "size": 1229 }, { "name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059 }, { "name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291 }] }, { "name": "Property", "size": 5559 }, { "name": "Shapes", "size": 19118 }, { "name": "Sort", "size": 6887 }, { "name": "Stats", "size": 6557 }, { "name": "Strings", "size": 22026 }] }, { "name": "vis", "children": [{ "name": "axis", "children": [{ "name": "Axes", "size": 1302 }, { "name": "Axis", "size": 24593 }, { "name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652 }, { "name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636 }, { "name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703 }] }, { "name": "controls", "children": [{ "name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138 }, { "name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824 }, { "name": "Control", "size": 1353 }, { "name": "ControlList", "size": 4665 }, { "name": "DragControl", "size": 2649 }, { "name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832 }, { "name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896 }, { "name": "IControl", "size": 763 }, { "name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222 }, { "name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862 }, { "name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435 }] }, { "name": "data", "children": [{ "name": "Data", "size": 20544 }, { "name": "DataList", "size": 19788 }, { "name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349 }, { "name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301 }, { "name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382 }, { "name": "render", "children": [{ "name": "ArrowType", "size": 698 }, { "name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569 }, { "name": "IRenderer", "size": 353 }, { "name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247 }] }, { "name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275 }, { "name": "Tree", "size": 7147 }, { "name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930 }] }, { "name": "events", "children": [{ "name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313 }, { "name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880 }, { "name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701 }, { "name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117 }] }, { "name": "legend", "children": [{ "name": "Legend", "size": 20859 }, { "name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614 }, { "name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530 }] }, { "name": "operator", "children": [{ "name": "distortion", "children": [{ "name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461 }, { "name": "Distortion", "size": 6314 }, { "name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444 }] }, { "name": "encoder", "children": [{ "name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179 }, { "name": "Encoder", "size": 4060 }, { "name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138 }, { "name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690 }, { "name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830 }] }, { "name": "filter", "children": [{ "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219 }, { "name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165 }, { "name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509 }] }, { "name": "IOperator", "size": 1286 }, { "name": "label", "children": [{ "name": "Labeler", "size": 9956 }, { "name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899 }, { "name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202 }] }, { "name": "layout", "children": [{ "name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725 }, { "name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727 }, { "name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317 }, { "name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003 }, { "name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853 }, { "name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411 }, { "name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864 }, { "name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174 }, { "name": "Layout", "size": 7881 }, { "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870 }, { "name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728 }, { "name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348 }, { "name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870 }, { "name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121 }, { "name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191 }] }, { "name": "Operator", "size": 2490 }, { "name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248 }, { "name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190 }, { "name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581 }, { "name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023 }] }, { "name": "Visualization", "size": 16540 }] }] }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you change the height aren't you overriding the math that did the layout for you in the first place ? Perhaps consider using the zoomable version: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle